# Convertview in getview() comes null only the first time in Baseadapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a customer list to show.In the xml I have a grirdview

```
       <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <GridView android:id="@+id/customer_list"
            style="@style/Widget.SampleDashboard.Grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

In the code i am populating the adapter using a customer array. The getview of the Baseadapter looks something like below

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    String todayortomorrow;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customer_detail_list,
                container, false);
    }
    return convertview;
    }
```

I see in the activity that only a single customer is getting displayed. The reason is convert view comes null only the first time. Second time it doesn't come null. How do I show all the customers in the list ?

Comment: Where is your `customer array` in `getview()`??? Post your adapter class code and your are not declaring any view for the gridview items, you have just inflated the `customer_detail_list` layout which is gridview item layout.

Comment: that is not an error (convertView  not null). It's how the adapters work.

Comment: convertView != null is the whole idea of view reusing, it means that when you have for example 1000 items in your adapter you dont have to inflate your view 1000 times but just few ones and reuse them when scrolling

Comment: you need to move all the `set` method outside of the `if` block, and add an `else` block to get the tag.

Comment: mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.customer_list);

Comment: customerlistadapter = new CustomerAdapter(ridedataobject.getCustomerlistdata());
                mGridView.setAdapter(customerlistadapter);

Comment: @haint tag? we are not talking about any tag...

Comment: This is how I am setting the customer list to the adapter. Should I post the adapter code also?

Comment: @pskink if the adapter has a large data set, then we better use a `Holder` and set and get the tag on it, that's what I mean.

Comment: I think that @BlackBelt provide great answer to your question. However `GridView` is a scrollable view, so you shoud not put it inside a `ScrollView`. The rule is to **never** put a scrollable view into another scrollable view.

Comment: @haint Holder pattern is almost always useless nowdays, see http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html and Romain Guy's comment

Comment: @pskink that's a good read. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I see in the activity that only a single customer is getting
>   displayed. The reason is convert view comes null only the first time.
>   Second time it doesn't come null.

That's the normal behaviour. Android allocates a pool of view of the same type, enough to fill up the screen. This is done to avoid waste of memory (just think what happens, if you need to show thousand of rows)

> How do I show all the customers in
>   the list

The easy and quick solution is to use the `convertView`, to `findViewById` the content of your layout and set the information accordingly to your data set